# Aligning shapes and quantizing distances between shapes on the plane grid?

Tags: transforms

I want to straighten the alignment of the angles of shapes so that they are straight running parallel with each other and aligned with the plane grid.

Where do I get to either reset and/or specify the rotation and translation x,y,z values to guarantee that everything is exact and symmetrical? (from a numpad1 perspective/camera view looking across the green Y line)

Comment: can you please add at least a screenshot/drawing or maybe your blend-file that we can better understand, what you want

Answer (score 0):

Location and Rotation values for the selected object are editable in the Properties panel :

Clic on the + on the top right corner of your 3D view or press <kbd>N</kbd>.

[image: Showing N-panel]

You can specify the rotation and translation for *x,y,z values*.

Tip: you can edit *x,y,z values* at once. This can be done by clicking on one button and dragging vertically to include buttons above/below. After the vertical motion you can drag from side to side (for finer control use <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging the mouse), or release the LMB to type in a value and <kbd>Return</kbd>.

[image: editing multiple values at once]

[Number Buttons reference in Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/controls/buttons/number.html)